# horizontalscrollview click event not working

Tags: javascript, android, click, horizontalscrollview

I implement HorizontalScrollView using this sample [code](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Android-HorizontalScrollView) and [this](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/) . I have fetch data from server but i cant find way to implement onclick listener ,
How can I make horizontalscrollview click event ?

```
ArrayList<star> actorsList;

actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

         centerLockHorizontalScrollview = (CenterLockHorizontalScrollview) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);        
            adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);      
            centerLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(MainActivity.this, adapter);
```

getView method :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

        ///   ////  ///// 

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    //// //// /////
    return v;
}
```

CenterLockHorizontalScrollview  class

```
public class CenterLockHorizontalScrollview extends HorizontalScrollView {
    Context context;
    int prevIndex = 0;

    public CenterLockHorizontalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        this.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

    }

    public void setAdapter(Context context,ActorAdapter mAdapter) {

        try {
            fillViewWithAdapter(mAdapter);
        } catch (ZeroChildException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fillViewWithAdapter(ActorAdapter mAdapter)
            throws ZeroChildException {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            throw new ZeroChildException(
                    "CenterLockHorizontalScrollView must have one child");
        }
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || mAdapter == null)
            return;

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        parent.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            parent.addView(mAdapter.getView(i, null, parent));
        }
    }



    public void setCenter(int index) {

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        View preView = parent.getChildAt(prevIndex);
        preView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#64CBD8"));
        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        preView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        View view = parent.getChildAt(index);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        int screenWidth = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        int scrollX = (view.getLeft() - (screenWidth / 2))
                + (view.getWidth() / 2);
        this.smoothScrollTo(scrollX, 0);
        prevIndex = index;
    } 

}
```